# GUID format not recognized (when is null)

Tags: vb.net

In my application I create a function that allow the user to change the settings of the app. This settings are stored into a table 'cause there's a lot of records. Anyway, the problem's that if the settings isn't valorized yet, when the application start and load the settings from the table take of course a null GUID field and the message:

> GUID format not recognized

appear. A code explaination:

```
Sub LoadSettings()

    Using dbCon As MySqlConnection = establishConnection()

        Try

            dbCon.Open() 

            Dim MysqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM settings", dbCon)
            Dim reader = MysqlCommand.ExecuteReader

            For Each row In reader

                Select Case row(2)

                    Case "company_name"

                        Setting.name.Text = row(3)

                    Case "company_email"

                        Setting.email.Text = row(3)
                    ...
                End Select

            Next
End Sub
```

This function is called when the `settings` form is opened. If the settings aren't inserted yet, I get a message of bad format. I want to know how I can avoid this message.

Comment: Yes on the "row" in the foreach declaration. I know Guid.Parse but I can't apply this on For Each row In reader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the `DataReader` correctly.  Consider this code:

```
Dim reader = MysqlCommand.ExecuteReader

For Each row In reader
   ... something
Next
```

`MysqlCommand.ExecuteReader` returns a `DataReader` object, but it is not - nor does it contain - a row collection you can iterate.  If you hold the mouse over `row` you should see that it is a `Data.Common.DataRecordInternal` object which does have an `Item` property but a reference like `row(2)` will only compile with Option Strict Off.

Used correctly, when you `Read` a row the data in that internal object is available via the indexer (`Item`) and the various `Getxxxxx()` methods.  This just prints the Id and Name from a table in a loop.  I cant quite tell what you are trying to do with your results...it sort of looks like a Name/Value pair type thing maybe.

```
Dim SQL = "SELECT * FROM Demo"

Using dbcon = GetMySQLConnection(),
    cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(SQL, dbcon)

    dbcon.Open()

    Using rdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        If rdr.HasRows Then
            Do While rdr.Read()
                Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", rdr("Id").ToString, rdr("Name").ToString)
            Loop
        End If
    End Using         ' dispose of reader

End Using             ' dispose of Connection AND command object
```

Alternatively, you could fill a DataTable and iterate the rows in that.  Seems 6:5 and pick-em whether that would gain anything.

Note also that the `Connection`, `Command` and `DataReader` objects are properly disposed of when we are done using them.